# Gracefully stopping generators

Tags: amphp

Consider the following code:

```
Loop::run(function() {
    Loop::onSignal(SIGINT, function () use ($w) {
        echo "Caught SIGINT! exiting ...\n";
        Loop::stop();
    });

    while([$jobId, $jobData] = yield $beanstalk->reserve()) {
        $response = yield $httpClient->send($request);
        yield $beanstalk->delete($jobId);
    }
});
```

To my understanding, when this code receives a `SIGINT`, the callback in `Loop::onSignal` will be executed on the next tick and thus the loop will stop and the program exit.

In this case, if `$httpClient->send()` in the `while` loop has not yet finished, the next line will not be executed and the Beanstalk message will not get deleted. The Beanstalk job will then be retried and that might cause a problem if the HTTP request is not idempotent. We can substitute an HTTP request with a database call.

Is there a way to tell the loop to not execute new generators and wait for the generators in-progress to finish when a `SIGINT` is received?

I've been trying to wrap my head around this but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such option, but you can achieve what you want in your simple application pretty easily by adding a flag.

```
Loop::run(function() {
    $running = true;

    Loop::onSignal(SIGINT, function () use (&$running) {
        echo "Caught SIGINT! exiting ...\n";
        $running = false;
    });

    while($running && [$jobId, $jobData] = yield $beanstalk->reserve()) {
        $response = yield $httpClient->send($request);
        yield $beanstalk->delete($jobId);
    }
});
```

This will simply continue with the current request and exit afterwards.